# How to Segregate matching data into one and unmatched data into another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have below data,

```
R1 <- c("15515","5156",NA,NA, "2857")
RC <- c("ACC","ZXC","ACC","QWZ","ACC")
R2 <- c(515,5156.11-,415-,1455-,886)
df <- data.frame(R1,RC,R2, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I have the condition that, R1 should not contain NA and RC is only ACC, which to be captured into df1
and remaining data into another data frame df2.

I tried doing subset but unable to get desired output.

Can this be possible to create such two data frames(df1 & df2) at a single instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both conditions (`!is.na(df$R1)`, `df$RC == "ACC"`) with `&` and use the result once as it is to subset `df` and the other time negated with `!`.

```
i <- !is.na(df$R1) & df$RC == "ACC"
df1 <- df[i,]
df2 <- df[!i,]
df1
#     R1  RC  R2
#1 15515 ACC 515
#5  2857 ACC 886
df2
#    R1  RC       R2
#2 5156 ZXC 5156.11-
#3 <NA> ACC     415-
#4 <NA> QWZ    1455-
```

In case you have `NA` in `df$RC`:

```
i <- is.na(df$R1) | (is.na(df$RC) | df$RC != "ACC")
df1 <- df[!i,]
df2 <- df[i,]
```

Comment: But it is creating unnecessary NA rows too

Comment: So df2 should have also no `NA`?

Comment: Since my actual data is huge, I am getting stray NA rows in both data frames

Comment: First code is absolutely fine but along with the expected data, I am getting extra rows which contain only NA

Comment: Oh then you have also `NA` in `RC`. See update for that case.